# Merging column names in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I wish to merge the Q2 and Q3 columns into a single column and row and rename it to Q3 vs Q2 and I would like to rename the 2018 row to QoQ. The first image is where I am at and the second images is where I want to get to.

Is it possible to do this in tableau? Unfortunately I can't share the workbook due to data sensitivity issues, apologies.

[image: where I am]

[image: where I want to be]

Update: I have duplicated my date measure and renamed it to what I would like to display which has worked for the first row of the column but the second row still shows 2018 and I have no idea how to change it to 'Q3 vs Q2'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a table calculation as you have, you can create a calculation to achieve your desired result. This is done by isolating the quarters.

Something like this:

```
(sum(if datepart('quarter',[Date]) = 3 then [Pa Requests] end) - 
sum(if datepart('quarter',[Date]) = 2 then [Pa Requests] end))
/
sum(if datepart('quarter',[Date]) = 2 then [Pa Requests] end)
```

Comment: thanks for the help with the calculated field this has inspired me for my YoY calculation also but I am still in the same position, I have the right values in my table but I still cannot change the column labels. I found a workaround where I created a duplicate dimension and renamed it. I then dropped this onto the column shelf and turned off the 'show header ' option but I am still left with the column showing 2018 and have no way to change it to 'Q3 vs Q2'.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Q2 column header, and choose ‘hide’ to only display the second column

Similarly, try right clicking on column headers and editing an alias